# Getting undefined error exception on newly defined Error() in js with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, sentry, raven

```
it('should catch exceptions',
            inject(function ($timeout) {
                spyOn(Raven, 'captureException');

                $timeout(function () {
                    throw new Error('My oh My');
                });
                $timeout.flush();

                expect(Raven.captureException).toHaveBeenCalledWith('My oh My', new Error('My oh My'));
            })
        );
```

And this is the console error I get.

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) $exceptionHandler should catch exceptions FAILED
    Error: My oh My
undefined
        at /Users/MyUser/App/src/app/exception.factory.spec.js:17
        at invoke (/Users/MyUser/App/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4560)
        at workFn (/Users/MyUser/App/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2518)
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? From the MDN docs I got this example:

```
try {
  throw new Error('Whoops!');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
}
```

that looks exactly what I am doing, so I don't understand how my newly defined error can be undefined...

Comment: angularjs is capturing the error, not Raven.

Comment: Also one instance of `Error` will not be equal to another in any case.